# Send All items of listbox to listview's firts column. But listview is in another form

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listbox

In my program, listbox3 is in the 1st from. I need to send all its items to another form called "print". In the print form there is a listview with four columns. I need to fill first column with those items.

```
Form 1
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    print f5 = new print(listBox3.Items);
    f5.Show();
}

Form 2
public partial class print : Form
{


    public print(ListBox.ObjectCollection list1)
    {
        string[] row = { list1};
        var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
        this.listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);

        InitializeComponent();
     }
```

[image: This is the error]

Comment: ok. And whats the question here?

Comment: You will have to add a new constuctor in your form two that does accept a list of some kind as parameter.

Comment: you are trying to add an entire collection of multiple objects as the first element of a string array. I guess you would like to loop through the collection and add each element to the first position of the string array. Don't forget to call `ToString` on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem arises because you are trying to add an entire collection of multiple objects (and of type `object`) as the first element of a string array.

you would need to loop through the collection and add item by item into the array:

```
foreach (var listBoxItem in list1)
{
    string[] row = { listBoxItem.ToString() };
    var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
    this.listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
}
```

EDIT:

**Never** try to manipulate control elements before the call of `InitializeComponent();`. This method does exactly what it says: it initializes all components/control elements.

The loop has to go behind this call:

```
public print(ListBox.ObjectCollection list1)
{    
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach (var listBoxItem in list1)
    {
        string[] row = { listBoxItem.ToString() };
        var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
        this.listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);
    }        
}
```

Comment: then there is an error.   "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

listView1 was null."

Comment: @NawodaWijebandara that is an entirely different problem. Have a look at my edit

Comment: @NawodaWijebandara you are very welcome. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
foreach (var data in list1)
{
  string row= data.ToString();
  var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
  this.listView1.Items.Add(listViewItem);  
}
```